# Using IN clause in db_query

Tags: database

I can't figure out how to add an IN clause in my query, using placeholders.

I'd want it to be something like:

```
$nids = array(1, 2, 3);
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid IN :nids', array(':nids' => $nids));
```

Can't find any documentation on this simple task. What's the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You are missing the braces.

Try this:

```
$nids = array(1, 2, 3);
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid IN (:nids)', array(':nids' => $nids));
```

For more information, see http://drupal.org/node/310072, especially the chapter on Placeholder arrays:

> Placeholder arrays
>
> Drupal's database layer includes an extra feature of placeholders. If the value passed in for a placeholder is an array, it will be automatically expanded into a comma separated list as will the corresponding placeholder. That means developers do not need to worry about counting how many placeholders they will need.
>
> An example should make this behavior clearer:
>
> ```
> <?php
> // This code:
> db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid IN (:nids)", array(':nids' => array(13, 42, 144));
>
> // Will get turned into this prepared statement equivalent automatically:
> db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid IN (:nids_1, :nids_2, :nids_3)", array(
>   ':nids_1' => 13, 
>   ':nids_2' => 42, 
>   ':nids_3' => 144,
> ));
>
> // Which is equivalent to the following literal query:
> db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid IN (13, 42, 144)");
> ?>
> ```

Comment: I knew I was close ;)
Thanks for the answer and the link!

Comment: what about the strings?
`node_types = array('node_type_1', 'node_type_2');`

Comment: Same, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 19):

#### Drupal 8

Use the entity query class.

```php
$query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('entity_type')->getQuery();
$query->condition('field/property', [1, 2, 3], 'IN');
$ids = $query->execute();
```

To directly query the entity database table, the code is essentially the same for other database tables.

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('table', 't');
$query->condition('column', [1, 2, 3], 'IN');
...
```

#### Drupal 7

See [Berdir's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/5296).

#### Drupal 6

You can use code similar to the following one.

```php
$nids = array(1, 2, 3);
$placeholders = db_placeholders($nids);
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid IN ($placeholders)", $nids);
```

`db_placeholders()` is needed in Drupal 6 to create the string that holds the values needed for the array. Drupal 7 handles all this internally as Berdir describes.

Answer (score 13):

In Drupal 7, you can use [`db_select()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) instead of [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7).

```php
$nids = array(1, 2, 3);
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n')
  ->condition('n.nid', $nids, 'IN')
  ->execute();
$nodes = $query->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 6, if your array contains strings, you need to tell [`db_placeholders()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.inc/function/db_placeholders/6.x).

```php
$colours = array('red', 'yellow', 'blue');
$placeholders = db_placeholders($colours,'text');
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {bricks} WHERE colour IN ($placeholders)", $colours);
```

Answer (score -1):

Drupal 8 update.

Also valid.

```
$nids = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node_field_data WHERE nid IN (:nids[]) AND status = 1", [
  ':nids[]' => $nids
])->fetchCol();
```

Comment: `db_query` is deprecated and will be removed in Drupal 9. It shouldn’t be recommended as a solution at this point. You also shouldn’t use the database directly for querying data related to entities; there are APIs for that

Comment: The recommendation is strictly Drupal 8 update. The current accepted answer no longer works for Drupal 8, because it lacks square bracket.
To reject this answer because it does not work for Drupal 9 another major version is disingenuous. It stops users getting an answer
that just works. 
The sentiment is a clear example of, Perfect is the enemy of good enough.

Comment: The question was asked for Drupal 7; the accepted answer works for Drupal 7. Other answers answered for other versions, but the original question asked for Drupal 7. What @Clive is saying is that, if this answer is showing which code should be used now for Drupal 8, it should avoid using `db_query()`, since it's deprecated and code should not directly query the database for entity tables.