# Using "IN" with db_query()

Tags: 6, database

First off, let me say that I've tried the Drupal 6 answer shown in [Using IN clause in db_query](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/using-in-clause-in-db-query) and it doesn't work.

I have a query that previously only needed to include items from a single taxonomy id:

```
$images = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title, f.filepath, 
cti.field_iv_source_name_value AS source, bf.nid AS flagged 
FROM node n 
JOIN content_type_imagevault cti ON n.nid = cti.nid 
JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfaf.nid = n.nid 
JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid 
JOIN term_node tn ON tn.nid = n.nid 
LEFT JOIN betterflag bf ON (n.nid = bf.nid AND bf.uid = %d) 
WHERE n.type = 'imagevault' AND tn.tid = %d AND n.status = 1 
ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT %d", $user->uid, 134, $displays_count);
```

The requirement has changed and we now need to pull images from multiple taxonomy ids. Based on the linked post above, I tried this:

```
$tax_ids = array(134, 139);
$placeholders = db_placeholders($tax_ids);
$images = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title, f.filepath,
cti.field_iv_source_name_value AS source, bf.nid AS flagged
FROM node n
JOIN content_type_imagevault cti ON n.nid = cti.nid
JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfaf.nid = n.nid
JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid
JOIN term_node tn ON tn.nid = n.nid
LEFT JOIN betterflag bf ON (n.nid = bf.nid AND bf.uid = %d)
WHERE n.type = 'imagevault' AND tn.tid IN ($placeholders) AND n.status = 1
ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT %d", $user->uid, $tax_ids, $displays_count);
```

I just get a blank screen there. When I turn on Devel and display the query log, what it shows as running is:

```
SELECT n.nid, n.title, f.filepath, cti.field_iv_source_name_value AS source, bf.nid AS flagged 
FROM node n 
JOIN content_type_imagevault cti ON n.nid = cti.nid 
JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfaf.nid = n.nid 
JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid 
JOIN term_node tn ON tn.nid = n.nid 
LEFT JOIN betterflag bf ON (n.nid = bf.nid AND bf.uid = 1) 
WHERE n.type = 'imagevault' AND tn.tid IN (1,5) AND n.status = 1 
ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT 0
```

I have no idea where the 1,5 is coming from in the rendered query. What do I need to do to make this work? Does it only work for nid when selecting directly from a node? If so, how can I use an array in the query? Do I skip the placeholder for that param and just put it directly in the WHERE clause?

#### Updated info

So it appears that completely aside from the strange case of 134, 139 being translated to 1,5, I also have another issue. Although the variable $displays_count is set further up the page to 5, it's still translating in the query to 0. (I've echoed the value out right before the query, and it's still 5 there, so I don't know what's happening or why changing the tn.tid placeholder would have any effect on the limit placeholder.)

```
$tax_ids = array(134, 139);
$params = $user->uid;
$params[] = $tax_ids;
$params[] = $displays_count;

$images = db_query(db_rewrite_sql("SELECT n.nid, n.title, f.filepath,
cti.field_iv_source_name_value AS source, bf.nid AS flagged
FROM node n
JOIN content_type_imagevault cti ON n.nid = cti.nid
JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfaf.nid = n.nid
JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid
JOIN term_node tn ON tn.nid = n.nid
LEFT JOIN betterflag bf ON (n.nid = bf.nid AND bf.uid = %d)
WHERE n.type = 'imagevault' AND tn.tid IN (" . db_placeholders($tax_ids) .") AND n.status = 1
ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT %d"), $params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, since we only have two options, I've decided to just go with an OR clause, instead of trying to deal with the IN.

```
$images = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title, f.filepath, cti.field_iv_source_name_value AS source, bf.nid AS flagged 
FROM node n 
JOIN content_type_imagevault cti ON n.nid = cti.nid 
JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfaf.nid = n.nid 
JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid 
JOIN term_node tn ON tn.nid = n.nid 
LEFT JOIN betterflag bf ON (n.nid = bf.nid AND bf.uid = %d) 
WHERE n.type = 'imagevault' AND (tn.tid = %d OR tn.tid = %d) AND n.status = 1 
ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT %d", $user->uid, 134, 139, $displays_count);
```

Answer (score 4):

The last three arguments you are passing to `db_query()` are wrong; you should merge them in an array, and pass that instead of them.

[block_list()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/block_list/6) contains the following code:

```
$result = db_query(db_rewrite_sql("SELECT DISTINCT b.* FROM {blocks} b LEFT JOIN {blocks_roles} r ON b.module = r.module AND b.delta = r.delta WHERE b.theme = '%s' AND b.status = 1 AND (r.rid IN (" . db_placeholders($rids) . ") OR r.rid IS NULL) ORDER BY b.region, b.weight, b.module", 'b', 'bid'), array_merge(array($theme_key), $rids));
```

Similarly, [blogapi_mt_validate_terms()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--blogapi--blogapi.module/function/blogapi_mt_validate_terms/6) contains the following code:

```
  $term_list = array_unique($node->taxonomy);
  $params = $term_list;
  $params[] = $node->type;
  $result = db_query(db_rewrite_sql("SELECT t.tid, t.vid FROM {term_data} t INNER JOIN {vocabulary_node_types} n ON t.vid = n.vid WHERE t.tid IN (" . db_placeholders($term_list) . ") AND n.type = '%s'", 't', 'tid'), $params);
```

In your specific case, your code should be similar to the following one:

```
$tax_ids = array(134, 139);
$placeholders = db_placeholders($tax_ids);
$args = array_merge(array($user->uid), $tax_ids, array($displays_count));

/**
 * Alternatively the previous three lines could be replaced by the following ones:
 * $args = array(134, 139);
 * $placeholders = db_placeholders($args);
 * array_unshift($args, $user->uid);
 * $args[] = $displays_count;
 */

$images = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title, f.filepath,
  cti.field_iv_source_name_value AS source, bf.nid AS flagged
  FROM node n
  JOIN content_type_imagevault cti ON n.nid = cti.nid
  JOIN content_field_att_file cfaf ON cfaf.nid = n.nid
  JOIN files f ON cfaf.field_att_file_fid = f.fid
  JOIN term_node tn ON tn.nid = n.nid
  LEFT JOIN betterflag bf ON (n.nid = bf.nid AND bf.uid = %d)
  WHERE n.type = 'imagevault' AND tn.tid IN ($placeholders) AND n.status = 1
  ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT %d", $args);
```